# Why is tomcat7 unable to find LoginModule class in JAAS

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jaas

I have an application packaged in a WAR which is running great on an existing Tomcat6 server.

I am now trying to deploy it in tomcat7 but am getting the following error as soon as I run the login action: Failed login. Reason: LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: security.jass.SimpleLoginModule

I have the contents below in the conf file, which is defined in Java's security.properties:

```
UserLoginImpo
{
security.jass.SimpleLoginModule required;
};
```

Changing the class name here (to a wrong one) will make tomcat say it can't find that one, which eliminates the cause "the conf file isn't being picked up".

The class should be in the classpath: it's inside a jar in the lib folder of the WAR.

What could I be missing?

Comment: `security.jaas...`, not `security.jass...`

Comment: Thanks Jim, that was exactly it. I feel so silly!

Comment: Don't feel bad, we've ALL done that before, and anybody who claims they haven't is lying :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jim pointed out, the package name was not correct: security.jaas, not security.jass.

Goes to prove you really need to pay attention to details.

Comment: Can ssomrone tell me the difference between those two class paths? I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Can ssomrone tell me the difference between those two class paths? I can't see it. EDIT WOW that obvious, but that slippery as well - Two 's' chars vs two 's' chars.