# Missing LoginModule in Tomcat 7 but not in Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat

I was working with tomcat6 it was fine,but when I upgraded to tomcat 7 ,it was showing some authentication error.
Tomcat7 asking about `LoginModule` class,but tomcat_6 never asked about it.

```
WARNING: Login exception authenticating username "admin"
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class
```

I looked at the `server.xml`  and `web.xml` too on both tomcat-versions but there were not much difference I have found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Why is tomcat7 unable to find LoginModule class in JAAS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804075/why-is-tomcat7-unable-to-find-loginmodule-class-in-jaas)

Comment: the duplicate does not fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Are you using a custom login module? Are you using a `context.xml` file? The [Tomcat 7 JAAS Module](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/realm.html) has a Tomcat 5 compatibility option `useContextClassLoader`. The default value is `true`, which is backwards-compatible with the way Tomcat 5 works. Have you checked this? Have you checked the [JAAS Login Configuration File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html)? Is there an Error / Exception in one of the Tomcat / Catalina Log files?

Comment: If an application is configured to use a custom login module but the login module is not found in the classpath, a "class not found" exception is thrown with a message such as the following: "WARNING unable to find LoginModule class: Missing class: Xxxxxx..." See ["Summary of Choices for Packaging Login Modules"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13977/loginmod.htm#i1006646) for related information.